# Strange x & y POST values being sent in form

Tags: php, forms, post

What are these x & y values that are being sent back with seemingly random values?
After submitting my form, I output the _POST array using print_r() to make sure my form is being submitted properly.

```
Array ( 
[user] => Richard Testani 
[pass] => sdf 
[client] => Kim Ronemus Design 
[api] => 3425yrt 
[email] => rich@kimronemusdesign.com 
[x] => 88 
[y] => 34
```

)

I've seen this in other forms, but just ignored them.
Right now Im on a Mac platform  10.5, running PHP5

Thanks
Rich

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your `input` element is of `type="image"` (or a `button` element containing an `image`) then the coordinates of the click will be sent, cf. [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4.1).

**EDIT**
If your input element had a `name="something"` the `$_POST` array would contain the keys `something`, `something_x`, and `something_y`.

Comment: Thats the case - thanks for the answer. While not a huge issue in my scenario can a button element submit a form or only a submit input element?

Comment: Yes, it can. Why else would you want a button (except for `type="reset"`)?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. It happens because you are using an image as your submit button instead of a true submit button.

Answer (score 1):

it's if submit "button" is replaced with `<input type="image" src="submit.png" />`