# Input type image causing confusion

Tags: php, html

I currently have the following code:

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
<fieldset class="form-search">
    <input type="text" class="input-text" name="keyword" value="Enter Keyword / Catalogue Code" id="textBox"/>
    <?php echo $form->error("keyword"); ?>
    <input type="image" class="catalog_search_top" name="search" alt="Search" src="../images/search_form_button.png" />
</fieldset>
```

My problem is that the image when submitted isn't doing the same as if its image type submit.

When submitting the form with the code I provided, would it be expected that it would go to form process.php and send $_POST['submit']?

Thanks

Comment: Why this send `$_POST['submit']`. you don't have any field named `submit`

Comment: Related: [Strange x & y POST values being sent in form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797894/strange-x-y-post-values-being-sent-in-form).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use a image as submit button you will have in php $_POST['search_x'] and $_POST['search_y'] instead of $_POST['search']

Answer (score 0):

when using an image button to submit it'll simple be a POST.

so check:

```
if ( $_POST )
{
    // process form
}
```

Or you could use - based on the 'name' of the image input:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['search'] ) )
{
    // process form
}
```

yip sorry as it's an image it posts co-ordinates, so search_x and search_y as stated.

Answer (score 0):

Just change name="search" to name="submit", it'll work as you want.

But why you need get value for $_POST['submit']? If you want to detect your page has received a request, just use this code:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
     // Do some thing...
}
```

I think it better!

Answer (score -1):

your field name first input is 'keyword', so in process.php try change $_POST['submit'] with $_POST['keyword'].

Comment: He's asking about the image input.